# Cannot ping ubuntu VM from mac os

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have an ubuntu VM running in VirtualBox. I am trying to ping it, but cannot. I have the network setting changed from 'NAT' to 'bridged'.

here is the screenshot of the ip address info:

[image: VM]

and here is the result of a ping....

[image: terminal]

i did some google searching, but have not been able to pinpoint the issue yet.... thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you use NAT mode, you will never ping the virtual machine from the host machine because it is the NAT restriction. But when you use the bridged mode, you should be able to ping the virtual machine because it will create a direct path as if both of the machine directly connected. If the ping is fail, perhaps there is some program or application that are blocking the network like a firewall.

Comment: So that means to use `bridge adapter` for the virtual machine